# Sparkline not loading in Table component while paginating

Tags: pagination, pentaho, dashboard, pentaho-cde

I am using Pentaho cde 4.8

I need to show Sparkline and Arrow in my Table component, I am using pagination in my table component.

My sparkline and arrow chart is visible While dashboard is loaded at first. Table component will show 10 rows per page and it will show all the charts as per my column type.

The problem occurs here, if I try to navigate to second page using pagination in my table then the charts are not shown and it will only show the values in the column. the same happens during when I use search bar in my Table component.

This is code I use in preexecution:

```
function f(){ 
this.setAddInOptions("colType","trendArrow",function(state){
return { 
includeValue: true,
good: function(state) { if(state.value<=100) return false; else return true;} 
}; 
}); 
}
```

**I can see sparkline and trend arrow during 1st load like below:**

[image]

**After page navigation, it becomes like this**

[image]

Comment: any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Avinash,

Try using Draw function.
The same code of preexecution is to be copied in Draw function.

If you need to read API details: https://datatables.net/reference/api/draw%28%29